# Who chould call viewWillAppear anyway?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

```
-(void)Complete{
    CM(@"complete");
    [BNUtilitiesQuick UtilitiesQuick].startForm=0;
    [self.view removeFromSuperview]; //This remove superView and the new view will be listNewController

    [self setSearchLocationWhenChangeSearchBar];
    if([self.searchListTemp isEqualToString:[cachedProperties singleton].searchList] && [self.searchLocationTemp isEqualToString:[cachedProperties singleton].searchLocation]){
        CLog(@"Don't do anything");
    }
    else{
        ...
//Blablabla
        //[Timer searchCriteriaChanged];
    }
[[BNUtilitiesQuick ListController] viewWillAppear:true];//It's not called if I don't do this

}
```

Part of me feel that it should be called automatically. Somehow I must have done something wrong when it's not called.

Obviously I don't want things to get called twice either.

So I ended up calling them explicitly. Somehow it feels wrong. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are very wrong. Most definitely about using the singleton on listNewController too.

Comment: that singleton thingy is experimental. I use a different style most people are more familiar with. So I am wrong. Does that mean that viewWillAppear should have been called implicitly?

Comment: just a question :) what is the parent class of your BNUtilitiesQuick ?

Comment: @interface BNUtilitiesQuick:NSObject{
    
} it's purpose is to just store the controllers for the applications

Comment: viewWillAppear is declared in UIViewController.h , it gets called automatically every time the view is about to appear. at some point you  have to use super in your implementation.that could be the reason why its not called automatically, because your BNUtilitiesQuick is not a class of UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you want some action to happen just before your view disappears, you can write your code in the `viewWillDisappear` method. This method notifies the view controller that its view is about to be removed from a view hierarchy.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{}
```

Comment: viewWillDisappear get called automatically. It's viewillappear that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

`viewWillAppear` is declared in `UIViewController.h` , it gets called automatically every time the view is about to appear. at some point you have to use super in your implementation.that could be the reason why its not called automatically, because your `BNUtilitiesQuick` is not a class of `UIViewController`

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't get called automatically in my case. I ALWAYS have to call that explicitly. For some reason it's never called explicitly.

Comment: [BNUtilitiesQuick ListController] is of type lilstController and is indeed a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: what happens when you call [super viewWillAppear] in your BNUtilitiesQuick?

Comment: BNUutilities quick do not have viewWill appear. [BNUtilitiesQuick ListController]  does. And yes I call [super ViewWillAppear] there. But the original is not called unless I do it explicitly.